# How to automatically fill a form field?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I would like to fill automatically a field when a certain value is selected in an other field. The columns concerned in my form :

[image]

I want when the value "Recrutement" in field [Nom Entreprise] is selected fill automatically field [Candidats Potentiels] with the word "Recrutement".

[image]

Should I create an event?

Comment: Yes, use Nom Entreprise AfterUpdate event with code like: `If [Nom Entreprise] = "Recrutement" Then [Candidats Potentials] = "Recrutement"`. Otherwise, don't save anything and just calculate in query: `IIf([Nom Entreprise] = "Recrutement", "Recrutement", [Candidats Potentiels])`.

Comment: Thank you for your help !! What I tried before looking at you comment is create an update query and after update I execute it. Idk if it is good or what you proposed is better for DB speed.... ?

Comment: Don't worry I tried your idea and it is much much better. Thank you so much @June7 !!